# How to prevent eleventy/nunjucks from escaping content inside a for loop

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

When using a `{% for ... %}` loop inside an included nunjucks template (e.g. `{% include ... %}`) in eleventy, the generated contents of the loop are rendered inside `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` blocks.

Here is the contents of the include:

**src/includes/recipe-ingredients.html**

```html
<aside id="ingredients" aria-label="ingredients">
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for ingredientData in recipe.ingredients %}

    <li><span class="measure">{{ ingredientData.displayQty }}</span>
    <span class="ingredient">{{ ingredientData.ingredient }}</span></li>

    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</aside>
```

... and this is what gets generated:

```html
<!-- Rest of generated HTML -->
<aside id="ingredients" aria-label="ingredients">
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ul>
<pre><code>&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;measure&quot;&gt;2&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;span class=&quot;ingredient&quot;&gt;cinnamon&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;


&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;measure&quot;&gt;3/4&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;span class=&quot;ingredient&quot;&gt;sugar&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
</code></pre>
  </ul>
</aside>
<!-- Rest of generated HTML -->
```

Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Markdown treats lines indented by four spaces as code blocks, rendering them as you describe. Could your template's output be being processed as Markdown or similar?

Comment: @deltab I will look into that ... my workaround was to wrap the offending content into a `{% macro ... %}` which enabled me to get past the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<aside id="ingredients" aria-label="ingredients">
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for ingredientData in recipe.ingredients %}
      <li>
        <span class="measure">{{ ingredientData.displayQty | safe }}</span>
        <span class="ingredient">{{ ingredientData.ingredient | safe }}</span>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).